# How to deliver email to a large number of people with using ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I'm trying to deliver email to a large number of people.
I was okay before with this code below.

But, I've just noticed only my first dummy account received email, and other didn't receive any.

This used to deliver email to all the users fine, then it was working perfectly before indeed.
Now I cannot find any message even in spam box.

I never changed my code.  Only the difference is the number of users compared to before.  I think it was working fine until when there were about 2000 users around.
Now, it's about 8000 users.

What would be the problem? and what should I do to solve this?

**messages_controller.rb** Here, there are over 8000 active users.

```
users = User.all.order("created_at ASC")

@users_emails = []          
users.each do |user|
    @users_emails += [user.email]
end

CallMailer.call_email(@users_emails, subject, body).deliver
```

**call_mailer.rb**

```
class CallMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default :from => "noreply@example-foo.com"

    def call_email(users_emails, mesesage_subject, mesesage_body)
        @users_emails = users_emails
        @mesesage_subject = mesesage_subject
        @mesesage_body = mesesage_body
        mail(
            :bcc => @users_emails.join(','),
            :subject => @mesesage_subject,
            :body => @mesesage_body) do |format|
            format.html
        end

    end 
end
```

Comment: You should use batches to send a couple of e-mails. I guess if you look into your mailers log it will say something that there are to many recipients or some other error. Have a look at rails methods like find_in_batches

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of different options for this, but you'd want to look at using a queue system such as [`resque`](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque)

---

**Resource Management**

The problem you have is about how to keep your app running whilst sending all those emails. Your code looks fine (I just glanced), and so I think the way you could achieve your goal will be to do this:

1. Set up resque on your server
2. Don't send your emails immediately -- move the deliver function to a different action
3. In your `call_email` function, send your email addresses to resque via [`Redis`](http://redis.io/)
4. Set up resque to process through the emails & pass them to an email function
5. This takes the load off rails, and puts onto the Resque system

---

I can edit with some code if you want. I just wanted to provide a top-level idea for you